# subprocess() arguments in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I have an argument in Python that is screwing up my subprocess() command.  The argument is:

```
--server-args="-screen 0, 1280x800x24"


args = [
  'xvfb-run',
  '--server-args="-screen 0, 1280x800x24"',
  '/usr/bin/python',
  '/root/AdamN-python-webkit2png-3ae4322/webkit2png.py',
  '-o',
  filename,
  url,
]
```

I think it's escaping the double quotes.  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's escaping the double quotes to me.

Comment: this should be two distinct elements of the list, the same way `-o` and `filename` are different.

Comment: args = [
        'xvfb-run',
        '--server-args=',
        '"-screen=0, 1280x800x24"',
        '/usr/bin/python',
        '/root/AdamN-python-webkit2png-3ae4322/webkit2png.py',
        '-o',
        filename,
        'http://www.google.com',
]
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 173: "-screen=0, 1280x800x24": command not found

Answer (score 2):

While you've probably figured this out in the past two years, I had this same problem today.  The solution:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['xvfb-run', '-s', '-screen 0 1024x768x24', 
                       'CutyCapt', 
                       '--url=http://www.google.com/',
                       '--out=google.png'])
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['xvfb-run', '--server-args=-screen 0 1024x768x24', 
                       'CutyCapt', 
                       '--url=http://www.google.com/',
                       '--out=google4.png'])
```

Assuming you have xvfb installed.  I am using [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) as my sample application that requires an X framebuffer to run (its a program that converts webkit pages to images and requires an X server).

Answer (score 1):

This is Python code, not a shell command line.

A shell command line eats the quotes to keep the spaces - in Python, the spaces are kept by a different means, so the quotes are passed on as-is and become part of the argument the called program actually sees.